# sencha touch 2 toolbar title from json

Tags: json, sencha-touch-2

I need to change Toolbar title in sencha touch 2 from json that comes from `http://example.com/new.json`. Maybe I should use AJAX call to get json and then parse it... but how to insert value to `title:''` Is there any possibility?

**Main.js**

```
Ext.define('Sencha.view.Main', {
extend: 'Ext.Container',
xtype: 'main',
requires: [
    'Ext.Toolbar',
    'Ext.Button',
    'Ext.Img',
    'Ext.Label',
    'Ext.form.FieldSet'
],

config: {
    layout: 'hbox',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            docked: 'top',
            itemId: 'navBar',
            title: 'app', // need to change 'app' from json dynamically
            items: [ ..... ]
        }
     ]
   }
});
```

**JSON** example

```
{
  data: {
    add: {
      application_config: {
        datasources: [
          {
            data: {
              application_title: "test2" // 'test2' should be passed as value to title
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you're looking for [Toolbar setTitle()](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.Toolbar-method-setTitle)?

Perhaps you're asking how to access the nested toolbar in order to set its title.

```
var newTitle = ''; // parse your JSON response here

var mainView = Ext.Viewport.down('main'); // 'main' is the xtype of your view
var toolbar = main.down('#navBar'); // '#navBar' is the component query to grab the component with an itemId of "navBar"
toolbar.setTitle(newTitle);
```

You can clean up the code above as you like, but I was intentionally verbose to explain the steps to accomplish this.

Comment: thanks for that. But what if I have json reader in sencha architect and parsing json in that way: `rootProperty: 'data.add.application_config.datasources[0].data'`
and in template `<div class="demo"> {application_title} </div>`
...how to make **setTitle()** then?

Comment: Exactly the same way. Just do it in the store's load event handler: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-event-load